# Achieve polling with Arduino and Lora Module

Tags: arduino, polling, spi, lora

I'm using Lora 1276 and Arduino to collect data from [here](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/blob/master/API.md) every nodes.
The example code I use is from here and it work successfully!
As far I know, LoraWAN is using TDMA to distribute the time to any nodes.
And polling by the gateway to get the data. That can make the nodes keep low power consume and let gateway to be control master.
I searched some information about preamble which is at the front of packet, nodes will decide whether to reply after received. If nodes receive a preamble that does not match,it will go back to sleep.
Is there any sample code for polling mode?
Thanks.

Comment: The library you link to is a LoRa library, not LoRaWAN. Also, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

LoraWAN Class B devices do indeed use TDMA for scheduling periodic receive windows.

Here is sample code implementing Class B. https://github.com/Lora-net/LoRaMac-node/tree/master/src/apps/LoRaMac/classB